# Cloning a div resets all selected items of the destination div

Tags: javascript, html

The problem I have :

I click "add" 
I select 2nd option
I click "add"

Problem : my first select-list's selected option index = 0;
This should not happen, but I can't figure out why it does it anyway. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function add(){
var div =document.getElementById('ruletemplate').cloneNode(true);

document.getElementById('rules').innerHTML += div.innerHTML;
return false;
}

</script>
<div id="ruletemplate" style="display: none;">
<div >
    <label for="rule">Rule</label>
    <select name="rules[][option]">
        <option>MAX PERS</option>
        <option>MIN PERS</option>
    </select>
    <input name="rule[][amount]" type="text"/>
</div>
</div>
<form>
<div  id="rules" >

</div>
<a id="addRule" href="" onclick="javascript: add(); return false;">add</a>
<input type="Submit" value="Save"  />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is doing that is you are setting the innerHTML which means the entire thing is reparsed.  You will need to append the element to container instead.  Try this it should keep each select's position.

```
function add(){
var div =document.getElementById('ruletemplate').cloneNode(true);
div.style.display='block';
document.getElementById('rules').appendChild(div);
return false;
}
```

Comment: @ManseUK that's weird because it retains the position for me on Chrome.

Comment: @qw3n im using `Chrome 18.0.1025.162` on a Mac

Comment: @user1331696 just as an aside - dont put solved in the title - click the little tick mark next to the answer that helped the most ...

Comment: @ManseUK I'm using Chrome 17 on Windows I wonder if that would be enough to cause it?

Answer (score 0):

The option element maintains its current selected state with the `selected` javascript property (not to be confused with the selected attribute, which corresponds to default selected state).

This isnt cloned - so you would have to update the selection manually

Note - you cannot have duplicate `id`s on a single document - when you clone you element you are duplicating `id`s

Comment: The innerhtml of that div has no id assigned, so there ar no duplicat id's.
 
    <div>
  <label for="rule">Rule</label>
  <select name="rules[][option]">
   <option>MAX PERS</option>
   <option>MIN PERS</option>
  </select>
  <input name="rule[][amount]" type="text">
 </div>

Comment: @user1331696 ok - just read this from the docs -> `The duplicate node returned by cloneNode receives a new uniqueID when it is added to another node` you will have to transfer the selected state manually however

Answer (score 0):

In some browsers (Firefox, Chrome..) the DOM object is not updated (the text input with its value and the selected option with the "select" attribute), so when you call innerHTML you get the original structure without values.

You have to force the DOM update of the object, like this: http://dev-answers.blogspot.it/2007/08/firefox-does-not-reflect-input-form.html